# Swift 3 Goes back to previous view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parse-platform

I have a log in function in my app that I'm creating and it seemed like it was working fine. I use Parse. Here is the login function.

```
 @IBAction func login(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    if self.userName.text == "" || self.password.text == "" {
        self.createAlert(title: "Login Error", message: "Please make sure all fields are filled in")
    }else{
        PFUser.logInWithUsername(inBackground: userName.text!, password: password.text!) { (user, error) in

        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()



        if error != nil {
            var displayErrorMessage = "Please try again later."

            if let errorMessage = (error! as NSError).userInfo["error"] as? String {

                displayErrorMessage = errorMessage
            }

            self.createAlert(title: "Signup Error", message: displayErrorMessage)
        }else{
            print("logged in")

            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "successLogin", sender: self)

        }

        }

    }

}
```

So the first check checks to see if the username or password textfields are blank and if so, it creates an alert. When i first start the app, it works like a charm. However when I log in with a user and log out, I'm redirected to the login screen where the username and password are blank. And i click login and get the proper alert saying "Please make sure all fields are filled in" and when I dismiss it, it automatically performs the segue as though the login was successful. Can anyone please help me?

```
@IBAction func logOut(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    PFUser.logOut()
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "logOutSeg", sender: self)

}
```

Also, this is my create alert function:

```
func createAlert(title: String, message: String) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }))

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

If i remove the createAlert method after the first if statement, it does things correctly so I'm assuming it's in that.

Comment: I am wondering if you are doing a seque to your login screen and then doing a self.dismiss inside the ok action. Could it be that the dismiss is undoing the segue?

Comment: @ryantxr I do a segue to the login screen when they log out but i don't see anywhere where I'm calling the self.dismiss operation

Comment: See: alert.addAction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're logging out of 2nd screen for the first time, if it comes to first logging screen by performing a segue, this could happen. That's why you get empty username and password. When you dismiss the alertviewcontroller in login screen by calling `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`, it dismisses the current view controller. Dismiss the logged in screen (2nd screen) instead of performing segue after logging out.

Comment: Okay thank you I basically got rid of self.dismiss and it works !